# How do you login as a super admin in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I cannot find how to login as super admin in Strapi V4 using endpoints.
I've tested

- `.../api/auth/local` with *identifier* (username) and *password*
- `.../api/auth/local` with *identifier* (email) and *password*

(400 validation error - I guess this endpoint is for regular users)

- `.../admin/auth/local` with *identifier* (username) and *password*
- `.../admin/auth/local` with *identifier* (email) and *password*

Method not allowed

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Can't find anything in the doc.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This way you can login as super admin:

```
POST https://host/admin/login
{"email":"email@test.com","password":"test"}
```